# I want to know how Array.prototype.sort works basically polyfill of sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I know how sort works in JS but want to know how Array.prototype.sort implemented, basically polyfill of sort function, algorithm or any other details

I'm unable to find here, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Why does it matter? Does it matter which sort algorithm the JS engine uses, or if different JS engines use different sort algorithms? If you're just asking how sort algorithms work in a general sense, Google can tell you that, or Wikipedia has [a long list of sort algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: I know how sort works but don't know which sort algo JS engines uses ?

Comment: array sort use merge sort algorithm. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224128

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, here's the specification for Array.protoype.sort: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11

It does not dictate what sorting algorithm to use, so that's up to the browser's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
The time and space complexity of the sort cannot be guaranteed as it is implementation dependent.

 function reverse(a[0..n - 1])
     allocate b[0..n - 1]
     for i from 0 to n - 1
         b[n − 1 − i] := a[i]
     return b

 function reverse_in_place(a[0..n-1])
     for i from 0 to floor((n-2)/2)
         tmp := a[i]
         a[i] := a[n − 1 − i]
         a[n − 1 − i] := tmp
```